# DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated

Tags: javascript, promesas, async-await

**DISCORD.JS**

Hola, buenas. Estoy teniendo un gran problema que no puedo solucionar. Y es que mi bot me esta dando un error muy raro.

Probé a comentar todos los comandos que usaban async/await, los revisé y estaban perfectos pero no funcionó.

También, intente hacer un try/catch. Intente mil maneras de solucionar esto pero no pude.

Muchas gracias y si necesitan más información dejen un mensaje y yo les proporcionaré la información.

PD (El error aparece al ejecutar comandos de economía tales como work, bal, deposit etc...)

**Error:**

```
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:8356) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either 
by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)

(node:8356) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Deberías de poner el código donde te de el error. Un saludo

Comment: Hola, no hay código específico. Cuando utilizo cualquier de los comandos que tengo en el bot aunque no sea con async/await me salta este error